# Componentes en angularjs v 1.2

Tags: angularjs

es posible crear componentes en la versión 1.2 de angularJs?

Comment: Si te refieres a `Component` tal como está definido en Angular, me parece que es un rotundo NO. AngularJS y Angular no son para nada compatibles, solo comparten el nombre y alguna otra cosilla. Angular fue totalmente reescrito para mejorar el performance y poder competir con React y Ember. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es posible crear componentes en AngularJs a partir de la versión 1.5, la 1.2 aún no lo soporta.
Te dejo el enlace de la documentación oficial [angularjs-component](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component)

Espero te sirva.